# Finding number of even n-permutations from rising factorial

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, stirling-numbers

How can one derive from the following equality the number of even n-permutations (i.e. the number of n-permutations with even number of inversions)?

$$\sum_\limits{k=0}^n c(n,k)x^k = x(x+1)(x+2)\dots (x+n-1) $$

where $c(n,k)$ is Stirling's number of the first kind.

Note:  number of even n-permutations is $\frac{n!}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

A permutation of $n$ objects with $k$ cycles is even if $n-k$ is even
and odd if $n-k$ is odd. So the number of even permutations is
$$c(n,n)+c(n,n-2)+\cdots$$
and of odd permutations is
$$c(n,n-1)+c(n,n-2)+\cdots.$$
The difference of these is
$$c(n,n)-c(n,n-1)+c(n,n-2)-c(n,n-3)+\cdots
=(-1)(-1+1)(-1+2)\cdots=0$$
for $n\ge2$.